# Why are the Angular files included in the <body> tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, seo

I noticed that Angular puts its script files in `index.html` after the `<app-root>` element in the `<body>` part of the HTML. I wonder why it is placed there and not at the beginning of the `<head>` section.

[image: Angular script files placed in the body]

This would *decrease* page loading time, in my opinion, because it would lead to Angular's code being loaded *before* all the other Scripts that might be in `<head>` (for example Google Tag Manager stuff). This way, the page rendering could start while the other libraries are still loading, leading to a faster rendering and increased SEO performance.

I could not find an option where Angular injects its code in `angular.json`, so I guess I'm missing something here.

If I'm not wrong, where is the option to include Angular's script tags in the head section of index.html?

I'm using Angular 12.1.3 and Node 14.17.3.

Comment: They add attributes like `type="module"`,`nomodule` and `defer` though. So I don't think it matters that much if you add it to the head or body. As for SEO, I don't think that's the main goal of an SPA; but that's just my opinion. I think you might receive better answers if you create a github issue in their repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the `index.html` file in the source files and you'll notice it's actually almost empty.

The body actually contains an `app-root` element which only serves as a bootstrapper (the application takes place on this element).

As the scripts need this element to exist before they execute, they need to be placed after it.